# add style to words that start with a specific letter and make them clickable in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following text:

```
var text = "hello @user1 and @user2 , how are you @user1 ?";
```

I want to add style to all words that start with '@' and also add click event to them to call a function. here is my code:

```
function findUsers(text) {
    return text.match(/(?:^|\W)@(\w+)(?!\w)/g);
}

function goToProfile(user) {
    console.log("go to " + user + " profile.");
}

function addStyle(text) {
    var users = findUsers(text);
    if (users) {
        for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            var user = users[i];
            text = text.replace(user
            , '<span style="color:blue;" onclick="goToProfile(\'' + user + '\')">' 
                    + user + '</span>');
        }
       
    }// end if 
    return text;   
 }
```

this code fails to add style to the second '@user1' and also it can not add click event to the words. is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: There are two distinct questions. _"this code fails to add style to the second..."_ -> [How to replace all occurrences of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string); _"it can not add click event to the words"_ - Needs a [mcve] (and possible error messages) for a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to remove duplicates from the result returned by `findUsers` method and instead of using `string.replace` use `string.replaceAll` since you are already having unique user values. plus you need to wrap your span tag `<span>` in anchor tag `<a>` to make it look like link. please go through the code snippet below which does what you want to accompalish.

```js
function findUsers(text) {
  return text.match(/(?:^|\W)@(\w+)(?!\w)/g);
}

function goToProfile(user) {
  console.log("go to " + user + " profile.");
}

function addStyle(text) {
  var users = findUsers(text);
  // this is  where you need to remove duplicate from array
  var uniqueusers = users.filter(function(item, i, ar) {
    return ar.indexOf(item) === i;
  });

  if (uniqueusers) {
    for (var i = 0; i < uniqueusers.length; i++) {
      var user = uniqueusers[i].trim();
      //wrapping span in anchor tag  here and use replaceAll instead of replace.
      text = text.replaceAll(user, '<a href=#><span style="color:blue;" onclick="goToProfile(\'' + user + '\')">' +
        user + '</span></a>');
    }

  } // end if 
  return text;
}

var text = document.getElementById('input1');
text.innerHTML = addStyle(text.innerText);
```

```html
<div id='input1'>
  "hello @user1 and @user2 , how are you @user1 ?";
</div>
```